# Fields not calculating in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

Using Lotus Notes designer I have created a form and added a field on that form that does a @DBColumn look up.  The form then is viewed through the web browser and everything worked great.

I proceed to add another document to the database using that form, now the original documents still render in the browser fine but the new document doesn't return anything to the field.

I tried removing the @DBColumn look up and just displaying text but nothing I just get 0.

The weird thing is if I rename the field to something diferent everything works perfectly but then if I rename the field back, broken, no calculation.

Does anyone know why this is?  It has happened to me with various fields through out my application.  I originally thought maybe it was a reserved word thing but I now know that is not the case.  I usually just rename the field and move on but there has to be an explanation.  Is it a caching thing or what?

Thanks for the info!

Comment: What is the name of the field you are using that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the type of your fields  Is it 'computed for display'?  If you have computed for display fields in a form, and the documents already contain data stored in an item with the same name, then the computed formula is bypassed and the item value is displayed as-is.

Comment: Thank you for some reason when I read "computed for display" a light went on. :) and it lead me to this article http://www.lotusnotebook.com/lotusnotebook.nsf/D6Plinks/DLEY-7LY3JX. I had originally created this field as editable and so it was previously storing the values then I went back and changed the field to a CFD so I had to go in to each document and delete that editable field reference and that cleared everything up.

Answer (score 1):

Fields not calculating could be a caching issue. Try opening the form, edit mode, F9 to recalculate all fields.
If this does not help, close the form, press Ctrl+Shift+F9 to forcefully refresh all views in the DB (could take some time). Reopen your form, edit mode, F9. If the value shows up, try using the "nocache" parameter on your @DBColumn.

Depending on your application design, there could be a number of reasons for the problem. Perhaps the view used for lookup is not set to autorefresh or the server does not refresh often enough because of high load issues.

Comment: Thanks Christian, That is good information, I will have to keep that (Ctrl+Shift+F9) in my back pocket to force a refresh.